# how to sign with raw transaction data - EthersJs, Infura

Tags: ethers.js, infura, calldata, sendtransaction

As the below picture display.

If I know the `raw transaction data`, then how can I sign this transaction with the `ethers.js`?

[image]

Thanks.

### Supplement

The `raw transaction data` is display on the metamask.

I use a dapp.

And in the app, every time widthdraw, it will return the raw data, and need I to confirm with the metamask, So I want to confirm the transaction with `ethers.js`.

[image]

[image]

#### Try

I had tried as these codes:

```js
const ALCHEMY_GOERLI_URL = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxxx';
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ALCHEMY_GOERLI_URL);
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(params[1]);
    let walletiWithProvider = wallet.connect(provider)
    const nonce = await walletiWithProvider.getTransactionCount(params[0])
    let transaction = {
      to: params[0],
      gasLimit: '300000',
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('5', 'gwei'),
      maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('20', 'gwei'),
      nonce: nonce,
      chainId: 1,
      data: targets.payload,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(String(formInline.amount))
    };
    
    let tx = await walletiWithProvider.sendTransaction(transaction)
    await tx.wait()
    console.log(tx)
    console.log(tx.hash)
    console.log(tx.nonce)
```

But this return a error:

```
processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":44,\"error\":{\"code\":-32602,\"message\":\"invalid argument 1: hex number \\u003e 64 bits\"}}", error={"code":-32602}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_getTransactionCount\",\"params\":...)
```

I think this maybe the `data` is error.

Thanks.

### Again Supplement

I want to withdraw the `ERC20 token` (not eth), and as the below codes, I just send eth to myself account.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infura RPC

```js
     const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK; // "goreli"

     const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(
                           network,
                           process.env.INFURA_API_KEY // infura api key
                      );
     const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY, provider); // wallet private key

     const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
        to: params[0],
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(String(formInline.amount)),
        data: targets.payload
      });

     await tx.wait();
```

References :
referring to the Infura docs here, seems like what you need is the above extract.
[Create eip1559_tx.js](https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/send-a-transaction/send-a-transaction-2)

I was able to successfully do a 0 ether [Transfer](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xde3168742bb09c53b5952c38e2c05a39a555903ed8f5f49d73c5aecbfa489cdb) with a message using the above code

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I had try as your codes. It also get errors. And I had added some detail to my question.

Comment: seems like you are using infura as a RPC provider if I am correct? I will update my answer according to your edit.

Comment: Ok, Thanks very much. I will try as you code. And Then I will feedback result to you.

Comment: It works, but I want to withdraw the `ERC20 token` (not eth), and as the codes, I just send eth to myself account. Please help, thanks.  I had supplement the result to the question

Comment: I had got it. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome:)